# Java/Groovy integration testing protected resources

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-security, integration-testing

I want to write integration tests for my application which is using JWT authentication.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new MyJWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new MyJWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

My groovy test:

```
 @ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Stepwise
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate

def 'findAll() test'() {
        when:
            def result = testRestTemplate.getForEntity('/findAll', User[])

        then:
            result.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK
            result.getBody().toList().size() == 1
    }
```

But I need to place a token in header. How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set request headers with `HttpEntity` passed to `RestTemplate.exchange()` method. Consider following test case:

```
def "findAll() test"() {
    given:
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()
    final MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer .....")
    final HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers)

    when:
    def response = restTemplate.exchange('/findAll', HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>(){})

    then:
    response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK

    and:
    !response.getBody().isEmpty()
}
```

You can also use `ParameterizedTypeReference` to specify return type as `List<User>` instead of `User[]`.